# nonce generation based on php session id

Tags: php, content-security-policy

On an small audience highly confident web application we are about use CSP to add a level of security. Most parts of the application could be moved to script files and script-src set to 'self' would be sufficient.  Some parts however still have to use inline scripts. PHP Session IDs are recreated on a regular basis. We're considering creating a nonce for the remaining cases. Would this code be sufficient for this case?

```
$nonce = base64_encode(sha1(session_id()));
```

upon logoff we reset the session id.
Would this setup offer a reasonable level of CSP protection?

Comment: nonce based on a sessionid is a bad idea. nonces need to be single use and sessions are not. see one of the answers to implement a  sensible nonce.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In order to create a nonce with a reasonable strength according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce) it should be used only once and preferable contain 128 bits of data from a cryptographically secure random number generator. In PHP that would be [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php). An example to create a nonce:

```
    $strong = false;
    $this->nonce = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(46,$strong));
    if( !$strong ) {
      error_log("Weak random for nonce");
    }
```

Which will log a warning if the nonce was based on a weak random. The PHP documentation is unclear about what strong/weak mean but I assume it has to do with an TPM available for random number generation.

A possible implementation on [github](https://github.com/theking2/php-csp-builder)

Thanks to @mentallurg for pointing me in the right direction. His answer was instrumental to the solution.

Comment: thanks for the vote down. It is highly appreciated. but it is the accepted answer to the question.

Comment: This duplicates the solution suggested earlier  And an entry in the log makes no sense, because...

Comment: 1) Nonce does not need to be cryptographically secure. It is absolutely fine, if it is predictable. The only requirement on nonce is, it just should not be reused. Means, even a simple counter can be used as a nonce. Means, you add unneeded complexity. This does not add any security at all.

Comment: 2) If it was non nonce, but smth that really needs to by cryptographically secure, like key generation, then logging and despite this continuing would be a security risk. Because if it was not secure, an attacker could have already used it it, and log entry does not make any sense. Instead, you should *interrupt* the operation, not continue.

Comment: @mentallurg take it from a developer  with a background in telco: log everything.

Comment: @mentallurg next time in an answer include a complete sample code. Not just a function name without much context. That was the reason for my answer, I might credit you though

Comment: To *"log everything"*: Did I say you shouldn't log? I said that despite you know a security problem is occurred, you ignore it and continue. Such approach promotes security risks and is not helpful for other users.

Comment: Pure programming questions are out of scope on this site. They should be asked at SO. That's why your expectation about programming details is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

The protection with nonce works reliably only if content returned form server to client each time has a new nonce. Each nonce should be used only once. Where as in your approach for the same session ID you will always get the same nonce. This will have only little protection effect. Instead, you should use some generator with more entropy, for instance `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.

Comment: Understood. I'm a bit concerned with the performance if for each request a new nonce has to be calculated. Also I saw (PHP) libraries that implement some sort of timeout after which the nonce is recalculated and thought this practice. But [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce) proved you right. Thanks for the tip with openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(). does that have to be base64_encoded?

Comment: This method generates a byte array. If you embed it into a page source  (HTML, JavaScript), it can have unexpected results, because some bytes can be interpreted as special characters. For instance, `0` can be interpreted as "end of text" and thus your page code can be truncated at the place where this byte occurs. Bytes `10` and `13` can be interpreted as "new line" or "carriage return" respectively, which also will lead to unexpected interpretation of the source code. That's why we should convert it to some text. Base64, hexadecimal or something other - it doesn't matter.